# Component Template - Parameter Schemas (2011 SP1 HR1)

Tags: 2011, templating

Couldn't find an explanation in the online documentation but the Parameter Schemas option on Component Templates - can this actually be used the same way parameters are used on TBBs?

After adding a test Parameter Schema to a Component Template myself, nothing seemed to be displayed in Template Builder or in the Tridion GUI (when adding into a component presentation list).

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the Parameters Schema option on both Page and Component Templates has been put there for future use, at this time it isn't possible to use them anywhere.

Basically I figure, usage should be when you add a Component Presentation to a Page, that should make the Parameters Fields available of the Component Template (at least that would make it similar to how a Parameters Schema is used on a TBB, which you add to a Modular Template).

For Component Templates we can use the Metadata Schema, but that works like fixed values for that Component Template (they can't be changes when using the Template).

The Metadata Schema on a Page Template already works like a Parameters Schema, you assign a value when you use the Template on a Page. So also there the Parameters Schema doesn't seem to have a usage option at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

The parameters on any **compound** template (Page Template, Component Template or Template Building Block) are available to the building blocks inside that template. So the building blocks inside the compound can *either* specify their own value for the parameters *or* they can simply use the value that they get from their PT/CT/TBB. When used like this, the container (compound CT/PT/TBB) specifies the default value for the parameter of the building block inside it.

You can see a good example of this in the Binaries target structure group (sg_TargetStructureGroup) parameter on the Default Finish Actions. The Default Finish Actions is a Compound Template Building Block, which in itself performs no actions and thus has no need for any parameters. But by specifying the Images SG parameter on the Default Finish Actions, it is automatically available to the "Publish Binaries in Package" TBB inside it.

So parameters on Component Templates and Page Templates are (like parameters in compound Template Building Blocks) most useful to capture parameters for the building blocks inside them at a higher level.

## Note

There is nothing in Tridion to keep you from coming up with your own template language for page and component templates - or allowing the use of your own favorite program language (*cough* C# *cough*) as a page or component template.

In such a case you will probably find a much more direct use-case than with the very simple compound template that SDL delivery with Tridion out of the box.

## Update

Apparently memory is a tricky things and there is no way to specify the parameter values for a compound page and component template in Template Builder. But when you open a compound Template Building Block, you *can* specify values for its parameters. These then serve as default values for the building blocks within it.

Comment: I don't have access to Tridion at the moment. Can somebody check the name of the parameter on the Default Finish Actions and update my answer accordingly?

Comment: So, unlike for a Compound TBB, there's currently no UI for setting values for a Parameters schema when it's set for a Page or Component template. Therefore this only makes sense if the Parameters schema provides one or more default values?

Comment: If you open a PT or CT that has an associated Parameter Schema in Template Builder, it will show the parameters and you can specify values for them.

Comment: Umm... Just tried this with a 2011 box and it doesn't seem to give me anywhere in Template Builder to specify values for a parameters schema that I attached to my Component template. There's nothing in the parameters window until I select a TBB that has it's own parameters schema. I have closed/reopened Template Builder. Are you sure, or am I being stupid?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Franks main message is correct, but indeed we don't have a location to fill in the parameters for Page- and Component Templates (those shouldn't be in the Template Builder as that is not the location where we use them). Unless we use them outside of the defaults of SDL Tridion, like Frank mentioned, when you build your own template language.

Comment: Hmmm... I could've sworn the parameters were shown for all template types. My bad. I am 100% certain that they (at least used to) show for the Default Finish Actions though. So when you add the Default Finish Actions TBB  to a PT/CT/TBB in Template Builder it should show you a single parameter.

Comment: The ones for the Default Finish Actions do not show when you open the Default Finish Actions, just when you use it in a Template. It's really setting parameters when used. It does of course mean that any parameters you set on the TBBs inside the Default Finish Actions are sort of fixed inside.

Comment: If you'd specify a value for one of the TBBs inside the DFA, that will override the value specified on the DFA itself.